# Using CTE to calculate cumulative sum

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, sql-order-by, window-functions

I want to write a non-recursive common table expression (CTE) in postgres to calculate a cumulative sum, here's an example, input table:

```
----------------------
 1  |  A  |  0  | -1
 1  |  B  |  3  |  1
 2  |  A  |  1  |  0
 2  |  B  |  3  |  2
```

An output should look like this:

```
----------------------
 1  |  A  |  0  | -1
 1  |  B  |  3  |  1
 2  |  A  |  1  | -1
 2  |  B  |  6  |  3
```

As you can see the cumulative sum of columns 3 and 4 are calculated, this is easy to do using a recursive CTE, but how is it done with a non-recursive one?

Comment: Your operation doesn't look like a cumulative sum to me.  Where does the "6" come from, for instance?

Answer (score 2):

Use window functions. Assuming that your table has columns `col1`, `col2`, `col3` and `col4`, that would be:

```
select
    t.*,
    sum(col3) over(partition by col2 order by col1) col3,
    sum(col4) over(partition by col2 order by col1) col4
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use a window function for a cumulative sum.  I don't see what the sum is in your example, but the syntax is something like:

```
select t.*, sum(x) over (order by y) as cumulative_sum
from t;
```

For your example, this would seem to be:

```
select t.*,
       sum(col3) over (partition by col2 order by col1) as new_col3,
       sum(col4) over (partition by col2 order by col1) as new_col4
from t;
```